# Trying to create modbus message frame using NModbus

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, modbus

I installed the NModbus nuget package, But using that package I can directly read or write register over port (COM).

But I only need to create message frame using NModbus and then I will send that frame over Bluetooth this will the second layer.

And aslo need to convert the response into message.

So, can I use NModbus package to create modbus message  frame only and also convert the response into message.

Thanks

Comment: Not really.  You would need to get the bytes, but then what addresses do you want?  See message strucutre : https://www.picotech.com/library/oscilloscopes/modbus-serial-protocol-decoding?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng I only need to create modbus message frame, for that function I only send the arguments like starting address, data or other and number of register etc. Once received the response then separate the data from response. So can I do that using NModbus? In nmodbus  buildframemessage function implemented but we can not access it outside.

Comment: The hardware an application software has to be co-located.  You can't run over a remote connection.  You need to write a server that will take inputs from bluetooth and write to the com port.